# Is it wrong to ask someone "Call me something" if you do need the requested thing?

Tags: verbs

I'll try to make myself more clear. For example, as I know, we can say: "Give me a book", "Send me a message", "Buy me a flower", "Bring me the cat" et cetera. So if I, for instance, need a fuel truck, could I say: "Call me a fuel truck, please!" If it's not good or, worse, absolutely wrong, then can you please explain why? Thanks a lot in advance. English is not my first language.

Comment: It's not wrong, but unless the circumstances are of a serious nature you risk getting the joking reply "You're a fuel truck!" (punning on the other meaning of _call me_ (address me as).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Call me a fuel truck" is clear and acceptable. It's obvious from this sentence that you want a fuel truck to come help you. Now, if you say this sentence to someone who likes "dad jokes", they might respond "Hello, Fuel Truck, I'm Dad!". Any native English speaker would know what you mean, though.

You could also say "call me a doctor" or "call me a mechanic".